# Graphing Indifference curve & Budget constraint for substitute goods

Tags: utility

I have two 'goods' - inpatient and outpatient healthcare units. In this scenario, the two goods are substitutes and I have graphed what happens when there is a decrease in the price of inpatient services but I want to just make sure this is correct. Due to the price decrease, the budget constraint has pivoted outwards and the consumption point has moved outwards - showing that people are substituting away from outpatient and consuming more inpatient units. I am just a bit unsure about whether or not this is correct as the indifference curve I have drawn is straight indicating perfect substitutes and usually when people are graphing perfect substitutes, there should be a corner solution but in this case, I am not showing a corner solution as I want to show people substituting away from outpatient to inpatient. If this is incorrect, what would be the correct way to go about graphing it?

Any help is much appreciated!

[image]